# Error while applying transaction in sequence container in SSDT vs2013 while connecting SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have migrated our batches to SSDT vs2013 as our database is getting updated from Sql server 2005 to 2014. When we are connecting the SQL server 2014 using the migrated batch in SSDT vs2013, then we are not able to use the transaction option on the container as required. It is throwing the below error.

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.   The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "OXFintransactionDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.   There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

When we are using transaction property as supported then, we are able to run the batch successfully. We have to use the transaction property as required. Could anyone tell, how to use transaction option as required in SSDT vs2013?

We have tried using BIDS 2005 and connecting to SQL 2014 with the transaction property as required. We are able to run the batch without any issue.Is there is any change made in vs2013 for using transaction option while connecting to SQL server 2014?

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with Transactions and Transaction Coordinator. The error is not being able to connect to Connection Manager, so you need to look after additional error messages with more details.

Comment: I am not getting any other error message in it or error logs.We are able to connect the database using transaction option as supported but we are getting error when we connect through transaction option required with the same set up. Do you any idea about any tool through which we can get stack trace.